# List manipulating data from two tables content

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables

[image]

I would like to know how to do to list the product table: ProdID, Quantity, Name, Price

and table productUser: userId, State

The problem is that I need to also list all the information of product table and adding the UserId field with the same value and the state looks for a default value would be false ..

It is possible? could also,  not to add the userId, State and drive it from my application code for assigning values​​. thanks

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: `SELECT P.prodId, P.Quantity, P.Name, P.Price, PU.userId, PU.State FROM Product P INNER JOIN ProductUser PU ON P.prodId = PU.prodId;` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to list specific fields from both tables but only when the child records match your criteria. If so, the query below would allow you to specify the userID and State.

```
SELECT p.prodId
      ,p.Quantity
      ,p.Name
      ,p.Price
      ,pu.userId
      ,pu.State
  FROM Product p
 INNER JOIN ProductUser pu
       ON p.prodId = pu.prodId
 WHERE pu.userID = @userID
   AND pu.State = 0
   --AND pu.State = @State
```

If my understanding is not correct, please post some sample table data and indicate which results you want returned.

Update to your update: I've defaulted State to zero in the query above. Followup question: do you want columns from both tables or are you trying to do an existence check against ProductUser to return just columns from Product?